# How get Most view video from video list in android ?

Tags: android, listview, video

I have one listview of videos.
in this given image one button  "MostView Video". when i click on this button then i can get list of mostview video.
so how i can get mostview video?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see the video then you can store the value in databse then compare it with all other and which 1 (or 10) is highest then they can see in mostview videos.

Girish